# GitLab - Problems with Curl - New Merge

Tags: gitlab

I have problems when I want to generate a new MR through the CURL. This is what I'm writing.

`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN_FINTECH" "https://$gitlab/api/v4/projects/$id/merge_request/" {"source_branch":"TestBranch","target_branch":"LAD-Wiru","title":"This is a test","state":"opened"}`

But when I run my job with this line, it returns the following

`{"error":"404 Not Found"}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

I searched in several places but I still don't understand how to solve it. :C

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to pass the parameters by appending them to the URI.

You're also missing an `s` at the end of `merge_requests`, and passing some attributes (such as `state`) that are [not available in the create MR endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr), so you'll need to correct those.

Most likely, you want something like this:

`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN_FINTECH" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1234/merge_requests?source_branch=TestBranch&target_branch=LAD-Wiru&title=This%20is%20a%20test"`

If you prefer not to append the attributes to the URI, you can use [`--data` instead of `--request POST`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/documentation/restful_api_styleguide.html#post-data-using-curls---data).